# How to create a promotion cart rule using user registration date as condition?

Tags: magento, rules, magento-ee

I wanna apply a specific discount rule for those users that registred after a determined date.

*Example:* Apply -10% over cart when user registred date is after 08/21/2017.

Is there a Magento's module or plugin where I can easily do it?

I am using *Magento Enterprise 1*

Answer (score 0):

With this module it is possible to make the combination you'd like to have:

`Special Promotions Pro by Amasty :`
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/special-promotions-pro-by-amasty.html

Comment: Thanks in advance brother. I will try it.